# in source code comments $ gets turned into £

Tags: pdftex, minted

I'm creating pdfs of source code using the minted package... and surprised to see `$` get turned into `£`.

`pdflatex --shell-escape create_array.tex` is the command.  `create_array.tex` looks like:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=20.06cm,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{solarized}

\begin{document}
\begin{LARGE}
  \inputminted[firstline=2,lastline=11,firstnumber=1]{php}{create_array.php}
\end{LARGE}
\end{document}
```

and `create_array.php` looks like:

```
<?php
// create an indexed array named $var with default indexing
$var = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
print_r($var);/* prints:
Array
 (
  [0] => item1
  [1] => item2
  [2] => item3
 )
*/
```

the `$` in the first code comment is getting transformed when it should not be...
[image]

The `create_array.php` file cannot be changed.  The solution must be done in the `.tex` file.  How can I prevent this odd transformation from happening?

Comment: A tip to anyone who cares to investigate, it appears to be a consequence of `minted` redefining `\$` as `\string$` for the purposes of communicating via the `\write18` mechanism. In Computer Modern italics, $ is £ which makes the LaTeX `\$` macro a bit more complicated than it should be. The simplest solution would be a font change.

Comment: Use \usepackage [T1]{fontenc}